# Should I use a Content Provider for 6 apps?

Tags: android, react-native, sharedpreferences, android-contentprovider

I'm using **react-native** to begin with, and here's the situation:

I have 6 apps that all share the same data. (not that it matters, but it's just a single JSON file/string) Users may own any number of these 6 apps. I used `Shared Preferences App Groups` and `Public External Storage` for Android. But the problem was that in API 29, Public External Storage was deprecated.

So I am wondering, if I create a Content Provider, will this work? Is the data saved in its own private space, and any of these 6 apps can read/write to it? Or is there supposed to be 1 app that has 1 content provider, and the other 5 have to access this one? And if this is the case, what if app #1 has the content provider, but the user only owns apps #2 and #3?

In the past, with `Public External Storage`, it didn't matter what combination of apps they used. And if the user deleted the app, or any number of apps, the data wouldn't be deleted. Do content providers work similarly? Will the data persist even if 1 or multiple apps are deleted?

The reason I ask all these questions is because I'm not certain if there has to be a parent app (the one that holds the content provider) and 5 child apps? Or they can all implement identical content provider code and thus are more like siblings?

Comment: `Or is there supposed to be 1 app that has 1 content provider` Yes. You can make a separate app for it. The one you called parent.

Comment: But you can still go on for Android 10 and 11 like you allways did. Maybe 12 will be different again.

Comment: So I wrote the code for the content providers. It fails. I have to have a 'parent app'. It seems as if sibling apps do not work. Like sharing 'gold' between multiple game apps won't work this way.

Comment: @blackapps as of this summer, we can no longer target API 29 or below and upload to Google Play. Once you target 30+, can't use the legacy storage anymore. Not sure what to do now.

Comment: Of course you still can request legacy external storage in manifest. Nobody said you could not. But it will work for an Android 10 device only. Further i have no idea what you coded and tried with contentproviders.